# Correct HTTP status code for when ID in the body does not match ID in the path?

Tags: rest, semantics

Suppose I PUT to `/api/resource/50` and in the body I have `{"Id": 12, ...}`

Is there a 4xx HTTP status for this mismatch? Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Right now I'm just returning 400.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Why does the client need to provide this information twice in the first place? It should be enough to identify the resource from the URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) Conflict?

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]

But using [`400`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure you return some details about the error in the response payload.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with code 409 (Conflict).
This wikipedia page is pretty handy:
[4xx Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors)